# How to migrate an svk repository to git, with history?

Tags: svn, git, migration, git-svn, svk

I have an svk repo that was full of mirrors and locals etc, I cleaned it up in steps, because I'm trying to get rid of it, and evaluating what should stay. There's only one project there that I want to keep working on, and for that I want to migrate it to git so I can be done with svk for good.

It's located in `//local/foo`, it has no svn repository.

So, what I think I want to do is create a local empty svn repository and push the changes from svk to it, and then use `git svn` to clone it.

But it's been so long since I last used `svk` I have no longer any idea how to go about that.

If one svk user would be so kind to point me the way…

[This](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/LocalSVKtoRemoteSVNHowto) is almost helpful, but it doesn't commit with history to svn, it just does a single commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
# create a local svn repo
cd $HOME/src/svk
svnadmin create foosvn

# mirror that in svk
svk mirror file://$HOME/src/svk/foosvn //mirror/foosvn
svk sync //mirror/foosvn

# finally, merge your local svk path into the new svn repo
svk smerge --incremental --baseless //local/foo //mirror/foosvn

# Just to be sure things migrated properly:
svn log file://$HOME/src/svk/foosvn

# Now, from svn to git
git svn clone file://$HOME/src/svk/foosvn foogit

# Again, just to be sure things migrated properly:
cd foogit
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

That's it. Then I did a bit of clean up:

```
mv $HOME/src/svk/foogit $HOME/src/foo.git
rm -rf mv $HOME/src/svk
# This gets rid of your entire svk existence. 
# Be very sure you really want to do this.
rm -rf $HOME/.svk
```